# What is the probability of getting exactly two tails after tossing $x$ number of fair coins ($x\ge2$)?

Tags: probability, combinations

What is the probability of getting exactly two tails after tossing $x\ge2$ number of fair coins?

I am not sure about my answer, but please allow me to share it here.

Let $A$ be the number of times we get a tail after randomly tossing an x number of different coins, where x is greater than or equal to 2. The probability of getting a tail after randomly tossing a single coin is $\frac{1}{2}$ (H / H, T). The probability of getting exactly two tails by tossing $x$ coins is

$P(A = 2) =  {x \choose 2} (\frac{1}{2})^x$, $x\ge2$

Any comments and suggestions will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean exactly two tails?

Comment: Yes, it must be exactly two tails.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

A valid outcome corresponds to choosing which two of the $x$ coins you want to be tails, this can be done in $\binom x2$ ways.

The total number of possible outcomes is $2^x$.

Thus the probability is $\binom x2/2^x$.

---

To feel more confident about my answers of problems like this, I always like to think of them in terms of sets. We have the possibility space $\Omega = \{H,T\}^x$, i.e., the set of all possible outcomes is the set of tuples of length $x$ containing either an $H$ or a $T$. An example of a member of this set is $(H,H,T,H,T,T,H)$, if $x=7$ (for instance). We have $\#\Omega = \#(\{H,T\}^x) = (\#\{H,T\})^x = 2^x$.

Now we want the subset $A\subseteq\Omega$ containing all tuples with precisely two $T$'s. To populate this set, we pick the two out of $x$ positions to place the $T$'s, and fill the rest with $H$'s. This can be done in $\binom x2$ ways, so $\#A=\binom x2$.

Thus our probability is $$\mathsf P(A)=\frac{\#A}{\#\Omega}=\frac{\binom x2}{2^x} = \frac{x(x-1)}{2^{x+1}}.$$